# Doing Html Markup in PHP

Tags: php, html, markup

I'd like to do my HTML markup with PHP using require is this possible and if so how'd you do it?

Right now this is the code in my index.php:

```
<?php


require('header.php')
require('body.php')

htmlHead();
htmlContent();


?>
```

Then In my header.php file i've got this:

```
<?php

 function htmlHead(){
 echo '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <title>Hello World</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">
        </head>';
}


?>
```

and then for my body tags:

```
<?php
 function htmlContent(){
 echo'  <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <p>Hello World!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
';
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Whats wrong with the above code. It should work.

Comment: NO. NO. NO. NO. NO. NO.   You can just include() a html file as needed. Avoid using the echo statement to echo HTML.  Just write HTML or PHP partials and include them.  You may want to look at a CMS later on, when you get more familiar with PHP.

Comment: that code should work as you have it, but check Jonah's answer for an alternative

Comment: there's no such thing as a PHP script. There's only files which happen to have PHP code blocks embedded within them. You could do `include('somepic.jpg')` and it would be accepted by PHP, **as long as** there's no `<?` char sequences in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to put your HTML in functions. You can simply do something like:

```
require('my_header.php');
```

And the contents of **my_header.php** look like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php $someVariable; ?>" type="text/css" />
  ...
</head>
```

Easy peasy.

Comment: Yep, this is the best way to do it. You can also check out the helper in Code Igniter, if you still want something similar. You will have to create/copy some of your own functions for various HTML elements. Not particularly useful though.